# Find all blocks on device not used by the filesystem

Tags: linux-kernel, btrfs, block-device, fstrim

How can I list all blocks on a device that are currently **not** being used by the filesystem? The filesystem in question is a btrfs RAID1 with two LUKS encrypted harddrives an Arch Linux.

I have tried `fstrim /path/to/fs` and log everything with `blktrace`. This actually works, but only if the hard drive supports TRIM - which is **not** the case here. (I have set up `dmcrypt` to allow TRIM).

The reasoning behind the question is this:

Two conventional hard-drives had been set up in a `mdadm` RAID with LVM+ext4 on top. Now those two hard-drives were set up with LUKS, btrfs RAID1 and data was written to this.

Unfortunately not everything had been backed up before the overwrite action. The hard drives have **not** been overwritten with random data before turning on LUKS, so the old data exists wherever nothing had been written yet in the current filesystem (I have verified this).

Now I am trying to recover as much as possible. My recovery strategy is the following:

Everything that is now being used by the btrfs filesystem can obviously **not** be the old data. So I want to find all blocks on the device that are currently **not** being used by btrfs. I then want to create an HD image the size of one those hard-drives, containing all the unused blocks. That would be my old data.

Actually, I don't really need to issue a real trim, I would just need to know what a TRIM would do. Or, simply find all blocks currently not used by the filesystem, which is my question.

Any way of doing that?

Comment: And what about `testdisk`? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really help in this situation. The two hard-disks were part of an `mdadm` raid, so they have the same data. The btrfs RAID1 now distributes the data differently on both drives, so different parts of the drives were overwritten (I have verified this). That's why I need to ask the filesystem which blocks are not used. I don't see how `testdisk` can help me here.

Comment: Try `btrfs-debug-tree`. Never used it, but I hope it's similar to ext2/3/4 `dumpe2fs -x /dev/sdXn`. Infact you need something like `FIBMAP`, I'm not sure it's compatible with `btrfs`. For ext2/3/4 even `hdparm` has `--fibmap` option  as FIBMAP implementation. Also check if something like `debugfs` is available to `btrfs`.

Comment: `hdparm --fibmap /path/to/file` bails out with `0,19: drive not found in /dev`. Possibly because btrfs runs on an encrypted device. `btrfs-debug-tree` prints out a lot of (too much?) information. I haven't been able to find logic in the output yet. I might be able to figure it out using the docs and source, but that will consume days. I will try `find /path/to/btrfsmount -type f -exec sh -c 'cat {} > /dev/null'` and log the result of this with `blktrace`. Still can't believe that there is no easy way of doing this. Thanks so far for the help!

Comment: Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458293/fastest-way-to-count-zero-bytes-on-a-partition